# Get href using xpath

Tags: php, xpath, web-scraping

I'm trying to extract 2 bits of data using xpath

1. text node value and
2. a hyperlink.

Here's my code:

```
<?php
$curl = curl_init('http://www.livescore.com/soccer/england/league-2/');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/534.10 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/8.0.552.224 Safari/534.10');
$html = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
if (!$html) 
    {
    die("something's wrong!");
    }

$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$result = $xpath->query("/html/body/div[2]/div[5]/div[contains(@class, 'row')]");

var_dump ($result);
foreach($result as $row)
    {   

    $text = $row->nodeValue;
    $href = $row->getAttribute("href");

    //getAttribute("href")

    $array[] = array
        (
        'text' => trim($text),
        'href' => $href
        );

    }
    print "<pre>";
    var_dump ($array);
?>
```

I just can't extract the href link!! Any help would be very welcomed.  Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

First of all, data rows in that page can be located by more specific class name `row-gray`. Then to get the link within current `div`, you can use relative XPath expression `.//a[@class='scorelink']` :

```
$result = $xpath->query("//div[contains(@class, 'row-gray')]");

foreach($result as $row)
{   
    $text = $row->nodeValue;
    $link = $xpath->query(".//a[@class='scorelink']", $row)->item(0);
    $href = $link->getAttribute("href");

    $array[] = array
    (
        'text' => trim($text),
        'href' => $href
    );

}
```

Comment: Approach makes sense, but I'm getting 'PHP Fatal error:  Cannot use object of type DOMNodeList as array' when I try to implement this.

Comment: @Bam answer updated with `->item(0)` replacing array indexer `[0]`